# if condition in permutation generator

Tags: python, python-2.7, permutation

I have permutation with 2 and 3 combination and what I like is to create a function or algorithm instead of if-condition, as you can see my code is growing big.
Here is my code:

```
esh = "e.sh"
gb = "g.b"
km = "k.m"
iv = "i.v"

perm2 = permutations([esh,gb,km,iv],2)
perm3 = permutations([esh,gb,km,iv],3)
for i in list(perm2):
    print i
    if esh in i and gb in i:
        print 'esh-gb'
    elif esh in i and km in i:
        print 'esh - km'
    elif esh in i and iv in i:
        print 'esh - iv'
    elif gb in i and km in i:
        print 'gb - km'
    elif gb in i and iv in i:
        print 'gb - iv'
    elif km in i and iv in i:
        print 'km - iv'
    elif iv in i:
        print 'iv'
```

If conditions will take action to surf in each https link based on findings from if condition, I have removed that part to make it more readable.
How can I create condition for 3 permutation ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need a function. You can replace all of the `if` conditions with a single `print`:

```
for i in list(perm2):
    print(i)
    print(' - '.join(i))

#  ('e.sh', 'g.b')
#  e.sh - g.b
#  ('e.sh', 'k.m')
#  e.sh - k.m
.
.
.
```

In case `esh, gb, km, iv` are arbitrary objects and not strings in your actual code you can simply implement `__str__` and then do `print(' -  '.join(str(e) for e in i))`

Comment: What if I want to take action only under “esh - iv” condition? @DeepSpace

Comment: @EdisShabixhiza You can add `if` conditions, for example `print(' -  '.join(str(e) for e in i if esh in i))`